# Text summarizer apart from Spacy for Python

Tags: python

Is there any text summarizer that could handle a huge volume of text (>10000) apart from Spacy which I am facing issues due to the text size? Are there any different text summarizer package for different scenario's as well (ex: summarizing a factual writing vs summarizing a fiction book)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use models from Huggingface, but be aware that a good RAM and GPU could be necessary with large volumes of data. Alternatively, ML cloud services like Paperspace can be helpful.

Here is the list of summarizers :
https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=summarization&sort=downloads

The most popular one is bart large:
https://huggingface.co/facebook/bart-large-cnn

You can test it and download it in the option "use in transformers".